# CUDA memory issue with allennlp coreference resolution API

Tags: allennlp, coreference-resolution

Hi I have some CUDA memory issue even though I am using multiple GPUs. I am calling coreference resolution API on long document (aorund 2000words). It seems that the memory is not paralleled. How can I solve this issue? (I am currently using the API as here https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The coref model uses a lot of memory. It does not automatically take advantage of multiple GPUs. The best thing you can do is reduce the maximum sequence length you send to the model until it fits.